# validation for 2 DateTimePicker (start date and end date) in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have 2 Date Picker control(start date and end date).

Where User should be able to select start date and end date.

End date should be lass then and not equal to end date.

I want  to give  validation when user leave the end date(DatePicker control) at that time.

Answer (score 1):

You have binded your enddate time with some property???
If yes then you can validate on its setter like this

```
private DateTime endDateTime
public DateTime EndDateTime
{
  get { return endDateTime;}
  set
   { 
     ValidateEndTime(value); // your validation logic
    ..
    ..
    }
 }
```